# PHP Fatal Error 500 instead of usual errors in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I've been working on building a website, but for some reason, Laravel isn't giving me usual errors with the gray background if something goes wrong, instead now I get a HTTP 500 server error.

When I'm looking into the server's error logs, here's what I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::error()' in C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php:2445
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(1245): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call('error', Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(1245): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException))
#2 C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1329): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('error', Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1329): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException))
#4 C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Excepti in C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 2445
```

Anyone has any idea what could this be? Because I haven't modified anything really. I'm using Laravel's 5.4 version.

I've been trying to search for a workaround/disabling some functions in the query builder but no luck - been doing this for the past 7 hours...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

No matter where I'm placing error in the Laravel application, I'm getting this HTTP 500 error everywhere.

If I'm using a fresh laravel installation, I still get the usual gray warning messages for the 100% same errors I'm creating.

**EDIT2:**
Replying to @Paras comment:

I have searched the full project for '->error' and only found this which has been added by me:

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories;

use DB;
use App\Model\ScriptLogs;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LogRepository extends Model {

    public function siteErrors($errorMessage)
    {
        $log = new ScriptLogs;
        $log->error_message = $errorMessage;
        $log->save();
    }

}
```

scriptLogs's file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ScriptLogs extends Model
{
    public $table='script_logs';
}
```

**SUMMARIZED:**
If I'm making **ANY** errors on purpose or without any - I'm getting the exact same error code as above `Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException'...`. I can **ONLY** see this error in the Server Logs file. Laravel's not saying anything specific.

Comment: Did you run a `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @Jackowski Yes, but it's still acting the same.

Comment: Possibly because it's a fatal error instead of a catchable error.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? PHP >= 5.6.4

Comment: Looks like you're calling an error method on one of your model instances like `$model->error()`. Because the error function doesn't exist in the model  class, it looks for a function like that in the query builder class because of the magic method `__call`. Please post the code where you set the error - that's probably the culprit

Comment: @whoacowboy Using PHP 5.6.19

Comment: @Paras Yeah I was thinking about the same but never used any `->error()` command before. I'm using GuzzleHTTP's newest version: `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"` though, not sure if it counts. Anyways I've updated my post.

Comment: When you say `new scriptLogs` is this an Eloquent model instance? Have you included `use path\to\scriptLogs` to import the class? Finally, if it is a correctly referenced Eloquent model instance, is there a column named `error_message` in the model's table?

Comment: @Paras I've just updated the original post with the full code. Yeah, there is an error_message column. My question is that why would this affect the whole Laravel system? Shouldn't it display any normal errors instead of these HTTP 500 server errors? Also, if I'm making any errors on purpose like `ddd()` instead of `dd()` or anything similar, I get the same HTTP 500 error. And If I look into the log file, I'm getting the Exact same error as stated in the original Post. Not even saying anything about the `ddd()`. That's what's really weird to me.

Comment: that's certainly wierd. If I were you I'd just `xdebug` this from the first line of code and try & figure out where the code is throwing the exception.

Comment: I've been using laravel for past couple of months, against my own will, and all I can say is that I don't understand why this framework is so popular? 
It's documentation is not useful so much, it's error reporting is also not useful (in case that it at least works, but it doesn't in 5.4 for me either), bad support for IDEs (using latest PhpStorm) and generally I've seen better implementations of everything Laravel has in other frameworks.
My personal opinion about the easiest framework for developer (and the most flexible one) is Yii2.

Comment: can you also search your code base for `::error`. It sounds like this error is happening early in the application, maybe in a service provider or a middleware or something.

Comment: It could be because of the permission rights on writing to the log. I had my log file owner user and group user. And I got server error because Web users can't write into log. Check your file permissions for laravel.log